# typescript literate over an Array without number index

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have the following array, lets call ist `lastID`:

```
 [valuePath00: true, valuePath01: false, valuePath14: true] ...
```

How can i iterate with an for loop over the array?

Comment: hm.. using the **for** expression in javascript? or **map** if you want to transform it to something else, or **forEach** if you want to do something with the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant an Object and not an Array. I don't think array's can actually have non-numeric indices, but I could be wrong.

```js
const lastId = {
  valuePath00: true,
  valuePath01: false,
  valuePath14: true
};

// For loop
for (let i in lastId) {
  console.log(lastId[i]);
}

// Object.keys() and Array.prototype.map()
Object.keys(lastId).map(key => {
  console.log(lastId[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a **forEach** loop?

```
lastID.forEach(item => {
  // do something with the items
});
```

If you really want to use a for loop, then you're going to have an index. Do something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < lastID.length; i++) {
  console.log(lastID[i]);
}
```